# I need a macro that will search for a cells in a certain column and copy all rows to a specified workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with a spreadsheet that has thousands of lines and out of those lines I need to search for cells in Col. B that start with "    E" and copy all the rows to a different workbook.  I have had no luck with searching for this specific question or if I have found something it was not exactly what I needed it to do.  The spreadsheet is updated weekly and i need a macro to do this search and copy and paste quickly with out me having to do the selecting, copying and pasting.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `AutoFilter - Begins With`

Answer (score 1):

If you changed the format and did some maneuvering with the data as suggested by stenci, yes you could avoid resorting to VBA. However, if you are in a position where you need to keep the format of the sheet the same and aren't able to manipulate the data as suggested (due to office-place bureaucracy for instance), here is a subroutine that should do what you are asking. I made sure to add plenty of comments to describe what each line does. I hope it helps, good luck.

```
Sub copyRows()

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
Dim bReport As Workbook, bReport2 As Workbook
Dim Report As Worksheet, Report2 As Worksheet

Set Report = Excel.ActiveSheet 'This assumes your sheet with data is the active sheet.
Set bReport = Report.Parent
Set bReport2 = Excel.Workbooks.Add 'This opens a new workbook
Set Report2 = bReport2.Worksheets(1) 'This assigns the variable for the worksheet where we will be pasting our data.

Report2.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Copied Rows" 'This gives a title to the worksheet (helps to avoid having to identify _
                                            the initial iteration of our for...next loop

For i = 1 To Report.UsedRange.Rows.Count 'Loops once for each row in the worksheet.

    If InStr(1, Left(Report.Cells(i, 2).Value, 1), "e", vbTextCompare) = 1 Then 'This searches the first letter of the value. I used the instr function to make it case-insensitive.
                                                                                    'You could also disable the binary comparison for the subroutine to accomplish this, but why bother?
        Report.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Copy 'This copies the row
        j = Report2.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1 'This finds the row below the last used row in the new worksheet/workbook.
        Report2.Cells(j, 1).EntireRow.Insert (xlDown) 'This pastes the copied rows.
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Note: Siddharth Routh might suggest using .end to find the last used cell as opposed to using the usedrange.rows.count, but I am used to the latter of the two. I may start using the former method once I am a bit more familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the order of the rows you don't need a macro:
Select the cell B1, click the Sort AZ button, select the rows starting with E, and use copy and paste.